# I connected my usb hdd driver. CentOS7 don't mount it

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount, centos-7

Unfortunately, my usb driver don't detect on CentOS7.

This is on message i got.

> Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at
>   /run/media/root/f4786057-a556-4cc8-a465-9b066b12a15b: Command-line
>   `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdc1"
>   "/run/media/root/f4786057-a556-4cc8-a465-9b066b12a15b"' exited with
>   non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad
>   superblock on /dev/sdc1,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>
> ```
>    In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>    dmesg | tail or so.
> ```

I check disk on terminar.
 fdisk -l

This is my usb driver.

> Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical):
>   512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512
>   bytes Disk label type: dos Disk identifier: 0xf24a25d9
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sdc1   *      206848  1953522687   976657920    7 
>   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

This is my system log.
[root@localhost ~]# dmesg | tail

> [ 1770.296794] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks:
>   (1.00 TB/931 GiB) [ 1770.297166] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is
>   off [ 1770.297169] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00 [
>      1770.297559] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA [ 1770.305222]  sdc: sdc1 [
>      1770.306469] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk [ 1770.676638] SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs [
>      1771.211761] EXT4-fs (sdc1): ext4_check_descriptors: Checksum for group 0 failed (23078!=0) [ 1771.211765] EXT4-fs (sdc1): group
>   descriptors corrupted! [ 1775.303256] EXT4-fs (sdc1): Unrecognized
>   mount option "ext4" or missing value

Comment: What's the USB HDD filesystem?

Comment: NTFS. Hidden in the third grey block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is not perfectly handling NTFS filesystem, if your Filesystem is created with windows just follow this step on a windows PC:

Execute diskmgmt.msc and detect the name of your External drive. Next step open the windows terminal and run this command :

```
chkdsk /f your_drive_letter:
```

Exemple :

```
chkdsk /f E:
```

Comment: your answer helps to find way..

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, my usb driver don't detect on CentOS7.

Your USB driver is working perfectly fine. As is the USB drive.

From you error message:
Command-line `mount **-t "ext4"** -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" ...

So the disk is detected and an attempt is made to mount a disk with an EXT4 filesystem on it.

> This is my usb driver.

That is an USB disk or drive. Driver is only one letter different but points to a completely different part of the system.

```
Device     Boot  Start         End    Blocks Id  System  
/dev/sdc1     *  206848 1953522687 976657920  7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

But this shows your disk to contain a single partition, one which is **not** in ext4 format. So you have a mismatch.   Either mount as NTFS, or reformat with ext4.

Comment: [root@localhost mnt]# mount | grep media
/dev/sdb4 on /run/media/root/18bac8aa-9d24-45a6-b17b-951293e162ab type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)

Comment: oh.. how can change format ntfs?

Comment: Are you sure you want to format the disk to ext4... does it have data on it? Do you use it on other (Windows) computers? Hennes is trying to explain to you that you've entered the wrong parameters for `mount` OR if you're definitely sure you want ext4 then you'll need to format the drive as ext4 (lose the data on disk)...

Comment: I don't want to loss data.. Is there any solution?? I want to recover all data..
How can solve this? use window recover program? or,, anythings else.